# Vb.net Listcount

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Receiving an error on the following line, any suggestions?

```
If lstbxCharacters.ListCount = 0 Then

    Else

End if
```

Error: Listcount is not a member of Windows.Forms.Listbox

Any method that I can call to check if the contents of a listbox is NOT empty?

Iv'e tried this instead now but it gives me a boolean error when the listbox gets populated with different methods

```
If lstboxCharacters.Datasource = "" Then
        Else
        <bunch of methods> 
End if
```

Fixed

```
If lstbxCharacters.Items.Count >  0 Then

 Else

End if
```

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If lstbxCharacters.Items.Count > 0 Then
  'data exists
Else
  'NO data exists
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

the list box has an [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) collection that you can check.  Google the control and msdn and it will show you all the members.

Comment: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'List(Of AccountEntry)' and type 'Integer'.< is the error I receive. 
Just cant seem to find a method that only checks if the listbox is empty or not